# Firebase Authentication, how to detect page is redirected result (or redirect to specific url)?

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am using Firebase Javascript SDK to authenticate with Google, using redirect method :

```
...
firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
...
```

The problem is I want to auto login during page load if and only if page is not redirected from Google Sign In. (preventing never ending loop)

**How can I detect if page is original one and not the redirected one?**

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for [`.getRedirectResult()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#getredirectresult).

> If sign-in succeeded, returns the signed in user. If sign-in was
>   unsuccessful, fails with an error. If no redirect operation was
>   called, returns a UserCredential with a null User.

```
async function checkRedirect() {
  const auth = firebase.auth();
  const result = await auth.getRedirectResult();
  if(result.user !== null) {
    // redirect 
  } else {
    // not a redirect
  }
}
```

Comment: This works, should be the accepted answer.